# Regex match for the given set of expressions (Extracting last column element )

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I'm interested in extracting the element found in the last column .

The issues is , that the last column might have an element that is in [ ] or is plain text .
In case it is in [ ] , then it can have ( , ) commas in it ,which means that a normal csv serparated string would not do it ..

So what type of regex matcher should I use to get the last element when it may be present in either format .

The format of the string is as follows :

*item_id,title,short_description,long_description,product_type,brand,prediction*

Example strings :

**32734061,The Cambridge History of Philosophy 1870 1945,short description is not available,"Hardcover, Cambridge University Press, 2003, ISBN13 9780521591041, ISBN10 052159104X",Books,NA,['Thomas Baldwin (Editor)']**

**48930358,Authors in Court : Scenes from the Theater of Copyright,"Mark Rose uses case studies to show how gender and gentility have influenced the self-presentation of authors in court and how the personal styles, public personas, and histories of novelists, dramatists, poets, photographers, and cartoonists have influenced the development of legal doctrine around issues of copyright.",Authors in Court,Books,NA,None**

ps : it would be great if someone could give me a a regex to parse all the columns individually , however the last token is of most concern to me at the moment .

Comment: try this regex, it work if number of columns is fixed: `^[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,(.+)`, see example: https://regex101.com/r/ymLc0k/2

Comment: @HieuNguyenVan : Fails for this : 48930358,Authors in Court : Scenes from the Theater of Copyright,"Mark Rose uses case studies to show how gender and gentility have influenced the self-presentation of authors in court and how the personal styles, public personas, and histories of novelists, dramatists, poets, photographers, and cartoonists have influenced the development of legal doctrine around issues of copyright.",Authors in Court,Books,NA,None

Comment: try this one: `, ?(\[[^]]*\]$)|, ?([^,]+$)`, demo link: https://regex101.com/r/tPeMja/2

Comment: @HieuNguyenVan : Fails for this :   21087801,Exercise and Fitness Training After Stroke: A Handbook for Practice,short description is not available,"<P>This . It aims frameworks, stroke.  be interested in physical activity after stroke."" <P>Exercise and Fitness Training After Stroke ""comprehensively discusses the  managed, the evidence stroke, how to design, deliver, adapt survivors.",Books,NA,"['Peter Langhorne', 'Frederike Van Wijck', 'Gillian E. Mead']"

Comment: @HieuNguyenVan : i.e when the last element is :  "['Peter Langhorne', 'Frederike Van Wijck', 'Gillian E. Mead']"  , then the parsing is not done correctly

Comment: An idea consuming the start part: [`^(?:.*\[|.*,)(.*)(?<!\])`](https://regex101.com/r/tPeMja/3) as a Java String: `"^(?:.*\\[|.*,)(.*)(?<!\\])"` might want to use in `Pattern.MULTILINE` mode.

Comment: If you are using with single items over multiple lines, use with `Pattern.DOTALL` or prepend `(?s)` for make the dot match newlines as well. See [this updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/jD0aOo/3). As a Java String: `"(?s)^(?:.*\\[|.*,)(.*)(?<![\\]\"])"` Well, I'm out - good luck :) Please update your question with your actual input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to get the last column

> ```
> /,("?\[[^\]]+\]"?|\S+)$/
> ```

your js code will be some thing like this

```
var string = "32734061,The Cambridge History of Philosophy 1870 1945,short description is not available,\"Hardcover, Cambridge University Press, 2003, ISBN13 9780521591041, ISBN10 052159104X\",Books,NA,['Thomas Baldwin (Editor)']";
var output = string.match(/,(\[[^\]]+\]|\S+)$/);
console.log( output[0]);
```

**UPDATE**

you can test your data here https://regex101.com/r/AZMOGA/1

Comment: Does not work when last column element is : ['Peter Langhorne', 'Frederike Van Wijck', 'Gillian E. Mead]

Comment: its working fine. you can check it here https://regex101.com/r/AZMOGA/1

Comment: Fails when last element is : "['Peter Langhorne', 'Frederike Van Wijck', 'Gillian E. Mead']"         p.s : This time , even quotes are involved , so some entries may also have quotes

Comment: its simple you can add "? at start and end. you need to try 

https://regex101.com/r/AZMOGA/2

Comment: Fails for this entry : 52927173,"Manual Drive Trains & Axles, A3",Details Coming Soon,"<div>
 <b>Manual Drive Trains and Axles</b> details the theory, operation, diagnosis, and service of modern This is a valuable resource to those preparing for ASE Certification Test A3, Manual Drive Train & Axles.
 <ul>
  <li>
   The text is correlated to the Manual Drive Train and Axles section of the NATEF Task List.</li>
  <li>
   Usage of drive train tools and service equipment, including micrometers and calipers, is detailed.</li>
 </ul>
</div>
<br>",Books,NA,None